# Как на Windows 7 уменшить время ожидания TCP соединений, при включенных многих адаптерах сразу?

Tags: сеть, windows-7

1. Сделал такую программу, меряет задержку TCP соединения, на .NET. С WiFi (но без подключения) скорость HTTPS 4000 мс, без включенного WiFi 1500 мс. При этом и WiFi и Eth пинг минимальный.
2. Задержка уменьшается если например выключить WiFi, Windscribe, Hamachi, и прочие адаптеры без подключения или маршрута приоритета не высшего.